# files are damaged after downloading from an ftp server

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp

Here's what I have:

```
    send(serverSocket, "RETR user.png\r\n", 15, 0);

    int iResult;
    int size = 0;

    do {

        iResult = recv(dataSocket, buffer, 30000, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            size = size + iResult;
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    cout << "the full size: " << size << endl;

    ofstream fout("test.png", ios_base::binary);
    fout.write(buffer, size);
    fout.close();
```

Here, I download a file into a buffer, and then create a file with the same type and write this buffer into it. The problem is that I can't open this file because it is damaged.

I tried to open this file using a hex editor, and it differs from the good one, but not that much. There's just some extra bytes and the whole data are shifted a bit because of them. **Where did they come from and how to get rid of them? What's wrong with my program?**

[hexidemical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCHYP.png)
(test.png is the one I downloaded, user.png is the good one, I downloaded it using my browser). I've marked 2 extra values, but there are more of them. I hope it'll be useful to figure out what's the deal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you send the instruction to use *binary mode*?

Comment: Why do the people insist in sending only snippets of code and not a full, verifiable example (complete, showing the failing case) instead of being so imprecise?

Comment: You need to read a little more of FTP protocol, as it is probably converting on the fly all new lines into CRLF pairs.  This happens in all POSIX systems (and probably on some implementations of FTP servers for windows, with pure binary files transferred in TEXT mode)  you need to set BINARY mode before your transfer takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
iResult = recv(dataSocket, buffer, 30000, 0);
```

The beginning of "buffer" gets overwritten with every loop.  You want to be appending to the end of the data already written, not overwriting it.

This is what you want:

```
iResult = recv(dataSocket, buffer+size, 30000-size, 0);
```

I'm assuming buffer is an array of chars (or unsigned chars, or anything with sizeof(1)).  If not, then this:

```
char* ptr = (char*)buffer;
iResult = recv(dataSocket, ptr+size, 30000-size, 0);
```

The other bug is because you're in ASCII mode with the server.  All those `0A` bytes are getting interpreted as an Unix linefeeds, and it's happily inserting the Windows carriage return, `0D`, chars before each.  I'm not sure if this is because the server is sending it that way, or your I/O calls to save aren't in the binary mode.  But whenever I do an FTP transfer, I always make sure to type "binary" at the command prompt so that the ASCII help isn't applied.

Look at the list of FTP commands, you may need to send the "TYPE" command to force binary mode.  And if that's not it, it's quite possibly the ofstream is...

[image]

Comment: ..or, writing out the bytes from the buffer each time round, instead of waiting until all the data is received.

Comment: There's always only one iteration, and I can just delete this loop and just type: `recv(dataSocket, buffer, 30000, 0)` and nothing more, the result is gonna be the same (the size of the file is about 15 kb). I also tried your code, and the result is still the same - I can't open the file and there are still those odd values in the hex representation.

Comment: @ShadeWe - it's not always going to be "one iteration" through that loop.  TCP segmentation, IP fragmentation, burps in the network and general internet behavior can influence the arrival of the TCP packets.  If the entire 15KB manages to arrive in the network stream before calling recv, you'll get all the data in one call.  Otherwise, it's a race condition and your code will loop multiple times. Whether or not that explains the corrupted file content you are seeing is another thing, but it's still a real bug in your code.

Comment: @ShadeWe - And now that I looked at your hex dump, it's very clear this is an ASCII conversion problem.  See my comments above.

Comment: **Both** things I called out were the problem. Make both fixes.  Glad I was able to help.